# How to update fat arrow function using prototype?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

Is there a way in which we may update fat arrow function using `prototype`?

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet = () => {
        alert("Hello, " + this.greeting + " inside");
    }
}

Greeter.prototype.greet = () => {
    alert("Hello, " + this.greeting + " outside");
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
greeter.greet();
// It should alert Hello world outside
// But it is showing  Hello world inside
```

Am i understanding fat arrow syntax incorrectly, and it can not be updated like this, any reference would be helpful?

[Here is the Link for Typescript Playground where I was trying](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%20%2B%20%22inside%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AGreeter.prototype.greet%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09alert(%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%20%2B%20%22outside%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeter.greet()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B)

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand what's going on better you should look at the compiled js code:

```
var _this = this;
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter(message) {
        var _this = this;
        this.greet = function () {
            alert("Hello, " + _this.greeting + " inside");
        };
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    return Greeter;
}());
Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
    alert("Hello, " + _this.greeting + " outside");
};
```

There is a `greet` function which is added to the prototype, but then when you create a new instance of `Greeter` this method is being overridden in the constructor.

It's usually better to have normal class methods:

```
class Greeter {
    // ...
    greet() {
        alert("Hello, " + this.greeting + " inside");
    }
}
```

Which then compiles into js with the `alert` already on the prototype:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter() {
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        alert("Hello, " + this.greeting + " inside");
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
```

If you worry about losing the scope of `this` when executing `greet` (because you pass it as a callback or something similar) then it's easy to just:

```
setTimeout(greeter.greet.bind(greeter), 1000);
```

Or

```
setTimeout(() => { greeter.greet(); }, 1000);
```

---

#### Edit

If you want to do something like this:

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    message: string = "";
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet(){
      return "Hello, " + this.greeting + " inside";
    }
}

let oldGreet = Greeter.prototype.greet;
Greeter.prototype.greet = function(){
   return oldGreet() + " appended outside";
}
```

It won't work as it will print:

> "Hello, undefined inside appended outside"

And that's because the `this` isn't the instance of `Greeter`, it should be `oldGreet.call(this)`:

```
Greeter.prototype.greet = function(){
   return oldGreet.call(this) + " appended outside";
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20message%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.greeting%20%3D%20message%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%20%2B%20%22%20inside%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20oldGreet%20%3D%20Greeter.prototype.greet%3B%0AGreeter.prototype.greet%20%3D%20function()%7B%0A%20%20%20return%20oldGreet.call(this)%20%2B%20%22%20appended%20outside%22%3B%0A%7D))

Comment: thanks for clarifying, I understand why it was not working, However I am still having issues with `this` binding, it is giving me undefined.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that uses `bind` and has undefined?

Comment: I have created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrG5hnYJS3kTnHblcVgN?p=info) for the same, Please have a look.

Comment: You can't do that, first your `Greeter.prototype.greet = () => { ... }` override the `greet` method without a way to call the previous definition. Second, the compiler doesn't understand what `this` inside the 2nd `greet` is, which is why it doesn't work for you. Can you please explain to me what you're trying to achieve with this?  Why do you need the 2nd `greet` function?

Comment: I have updated the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrG5hnYJS3kTnHblcVgN?p=preview) with actual scenario, I am trying to update the greet method so that it may take the latest function in the class or latest function attached via prototype and enhance with new functionality.

Comment: Why would you like to do something like that? What's wrong with just extending the `Greeter` class with let's say `EnhancedGreeter` and then overriding the `greet` method? That's what object oriented is for! You're working WAY too hard for something very simple

Comment: Yes, that's correct, if I just extend the Class it will work,I was exploring if the method may be updated without extending it so that the greet method may be updated in run time  based upon some condition.

Comment: Well, it is possible to do, check my revised answer.

Comment: perfect that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Greeter object. It sets:

```
this.greet = function () {
  alert("Hello, " + _this.greeting + "inside");
};
```

So it will override what you set in prototype. If you don't write the same greet() function, then it will call what you set in prototype.

Another thing to remember is that when you use arrow function:

```
Greeter.prototype.greet = () => {
  alert("Hello, " + this.greeting + " outside");
}
```

`this.` here is not the object itself, but it belongs to the outer context, that means you can't get this.greeting correctly.